# Some variables do not exist in the current context in Rider Debugger mode

Tags: c#, rider

I am trying to get the inspect the values of local variables. This feature works for some variables. For those that it doesn't, Rider brings up an error:

```
The name `variable_name` does not exists in the current context.
```

And image example of code and debugger watch error:

[image]
[image]

This is decompiled code, but even here it works for some local variables. What could be the fix for this?

I already check `Settings->Build, Execution, Deployment->Disable JIT optimization on module load (.NET/.NET Core only)`, but as it says, it only works for .NET/.NET Core modules

Comment: Could be that the assembly was compiled in Release and the variable was optimized away?

Comment: Not sure, I haven't compiled it my self. How can I check?

Comment: Open the assembly in [JustCompile](https://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx) or [ILSpy](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy) and look for the [AssemblyConfiguration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assemblyconfigurationattribute?view=netframework-4.8) attribute at the assembly level

Comment: Thank you! Indeed the assembly is marked as Release. I have access to the source code for the assembly in question, but it is maintained as a different project. I have compiled the source again in a Debug option. The tricky part is how to replace the .dll file. If I just got to explorer and replace it, I am getting an error that the `The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.`

Comment: It seems there are differences between Debug assembly and the Release assembly. My guess is either the assembly version or the Public Key Token. You can enable [Fusion Log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255669/how-to-enable-assembly-bind-failure-logging-fusion-in-net) to see the reason the binding to the new assembly failed.

Comment: Same issue. My project was running in release mode.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. In my case, the use of [Fody](https://github.com/Fody/Fody) was causing the problem, although the assembly was compiled in the Debug mode. After disabling Fody, I could see the variable value while debugging.
I thought this might be useful for someone else. Please check if your project is using any IL manipulation tools, such as Fody.